# TypeScript: AWS CDK setting resource tags with loop

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I've faced a Circular dependency error. I'm about to create an aws tag, but I don't want to add each time the class instance; instead I've created a function, which iterates over a given object and applies them to tags.

Iterator:

```
 ....
 ResourceTagger = (this, id, props: cdk.CfnTag[]) => {
   props.forEach(tag => {
             cdk.Tags.of(this).add(tag.key, tag.value)
   })
 }
```

Function Call

```
....
ResourceTagger(this.vpc, id, [
 {
   key: "Stack",
   value: id,
 },
 {
   key: "Cidr IPv4",
   value: this.vpc.vpcCidrBlock,
 }
```

])

Error Message:

```
❌ Deployment failed: Error: Stack Deployments Failed: ValidationError: Circular dependency between resources:
```

Is there an efficient solution for this code, as well maybe there are a way without using `cdk.CfnTag[]` interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `this.vpc.vpcCidrBlock` which you're trying to use within your `ResourceTagger`. By default `ec2.Vpc construct` , creates many resources, which are not managed unless, if they are explicitly defined.

So in your case, when you adding a Tag some aws resources which are symbol sensitive, throws an error: `ValidationError`. If you want to add `vpcCidrBlock` try to change to string, and that should help.

As for `cdk.CfnTag[]`:
You can try something like this:

```
ResourceTagger = (this, props: Record<string, string>) => {
Object.entries(props).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  cdk.Tags.of(this).add(key, value)
});

ResourceTagger(this, {
"Foo1": "Bar1",
"Foo2": "Bar2",
})
```